# How to use scanner and next() but not moving forward

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a scanner with the build-in next()-method, the problem is that I want to store two different values this way, It's probably easier to understand with my code:

```
public Sokoban8() throws Exception {
    file = new File("C:/Users/joaki/Desktop/sokoban/readin3.txt");
    sc = new Scanner(file);
    sc.reset();
    list = new ArrayList<Character>();
    sc.useDelimiter("s*");
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
        //String line = sc.nextLine();

        list.add(c);
        lines++;
        //if (maxChar < line.length()) {
            //maxChar = line.length();
        }
    }
    sc.close();
    for (Object item : list) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I remove the //, my code will iterate forward (twice), therefore I will not get all the values, is there a way for me to walk around this?

Comment: Just call `next()` once and operate on that string, e.g. `Sting line = sc.nextLine();` and then `line.charAt(0)` etc.

Comment: try storing String tmp = sc.next(); char c = tmp.charAt(0); char d = tmp.charAt(1);

Comment: I did try them both, it seems like they are both working, much appreciated, this has always been a concern for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store a line and a char during one iteration. You can store the line first

```
String line = sc.nextLine();
```

Then store the first char of it like this

```
char c = line.charAt(0);
```